# How can I know if related data is included when using eager loading in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on a project that is using Repository pattern. We are using Entity Framework to retrieve data from the database. To load related data we use eager loading which means that we have to explicitly **include** related data.

Say that we want to have all blogs and their related posts we would have to write:

```
_dbContext.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts)
```

The disadvantages with this is that you can only see which related data is loaded in the repository class.

I have tried to shown an example below. Here the problem occurs in the class `BlogViewModel.cs` because you try to access `blogs.Posts`, but posts is not included in the original query. So if you are trying to get related data, one would have to check the origin of query and see if it is included.

`Repository.cs`:

```
public IEnumerable<BlogDbModel> GetBlogs()
{
    return _dbContext.Blogs.ToList();
}
```

`Service.cs`:

```
public IEnumerable<BlogViewModel> GetBlogs()  
{
    return _repository.Select(x => new BlogViewModel(x));
}
```

`BlogViewModel.cs`:

```
public class BlogViewModel 
{
    public BlogViewModel(BlogDbModel blogDbModel)  
    {
        Name = blogDbModel.Name;
        Posts = blogDbModel.Posts;
    }
 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Posts> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Does anyone have a smart solution to this? Is it possible give an compilation error if you are trying to access data that is not included?

Two options that I have thought about are:

1. Use lazy-loading instead
2. Always return an `IQueryable` from the repository

Thanks

Comment: Could you share a snippet of the output when you include the posts in the query?

Comment: [ { Name: 'Johnnys blog', Posts: [ { title: 'life on the road}' text: 'hello everyone... }, { title: 'Where am I}' text: 'So cool... ]}], {  Name: 'Chrisitinas place' ,Posts: [ ....... ] } ]

Comment: Is that what you meant @Innominatum ? :S

Comment: Yes, looking at your snippet the Posts list is loaded but empty, does the data of BlogViewModel and Posts have a relationship?

Comment: I think my question may have interpreted the wrong way. @Eldho got it. thanks for trying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you dont have any option to give compilation error on this context. Data either way are loaded in the run-time.

**LazyLoading**
Assuming your displaying Blogs, Posts, Comments in view, So you need to load everything when the page load. 
When you enable `lazyload` and map properties that not been included in the data layer query it will load related entities

```
public BlogViewModel(BlogDbModel blogDbModel) 
{
  Name = blogDbModel.Name;
  Posts = blogDbModel.Posts;
 }
```

If you enable lazyload and do this post will be fetched using lazyload feature. What if post contains a reference to `User` or any other object it will load those too.
When you need everything at first place its not recommended to use lazyload because it will additional round-trip to database.

**IQueryable from repository**

I would say IQueryable to a viewmodel is leaky abstraction. Ideally your data layer should be performing these. Providing `IQuerable<BlogDbModel>` to Viewmodel is like developer able to fetch 1Blogs=>Post=>User=>Accounts1 anything related from this.

IMHO I would write data layer methods which are needed for the view.

`LazyloadingEnabled = false;`

```
public IEnumerable<BlogDbModel> GetBlogs()
{

    return _dbContext.Blogs.ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<BlogDbModel> GetBlogsAndPosts()
{

  return _dbContext.Blogs.Include("Posts").ToList();
}

//This will fetch only what is needed (You can customize to get columns what is needed)
public IEnumerable<NewCustomDTO> GetBlogsAndPostCount()
{

   return _dbContext.Blogs.Select(x=> NewCustomDTO
   {
       BlogName = x.BlogName,
       Count = x.Posts.Count(),
   });
}
```

Comment: Alright. that is a good point. The problem with this approach is that *Blogs* has ten related entities which again has some entities. So one would have to make a lot of methods in the repository. GetBlogsAndPosts, GetBlogsAndPostsAndAuthors etc. I guess my approach will be a  simple GetBlogs endpoint and a GetBlogsAndRelatedData endpoint.

Comment: I think GetBlogs is always need authors , comments and likes. Simple methods like GetBlogs which only return blogs is necessary when your using it. I would say write methods whats necessary. There is no silver bullet in development but trade off's are there get best for your situation

Comment: The case with blogs and posts was just for the example :). In reality it something much more boring :). Thanks again

Comment: some reference thoughts of lazy loading https://ardalis.com/avoid-lazy-loading-entities-in-asp-net-applications